# validate userinput in C#

Tags: c#, validation, console

My question is how do i validate the SIN the user inputs into my program i can't seem to get the IF to print whether it's valid or not, i'm also unsure as to how i can make it so that when the SIN inputted is invalid the program asks for the sin once more but if it is invalid a second time the program should close.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace sinValidator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Variables


            Int32 numbers1, numbers2, numbers3, numbers4, numbers5, numbers6, numbers7, numbers8, numbers9;
            Int32 sin;
            bool valid;
            Int32 sum;
            Int32 product;
            double test;

            {

                // Prompt for user input
                Console.WriteLine("\n Enter SIN: ");
                sin = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                // spliting the SIN into 9 seperate digits in different variables, and then printing them.

                Console.WriteLine("The first digit is {0}", numbers1 = (sin / 100000000));

                Console.WriteLine("The second digit is {0}", numbers2 = (sin % 100000000 / 10000000));

                Console.WriteLine("The third digit is {0}", numbers3 = (sin % 10000000 / 1000000));

                Console.WriteLine("The fifth digit is {0}", numbers4 = (sin % 1000000 / 100000));

                Console.WriteLine("The sixth digit is {0}", numbers5 = (sin % 100000 / 10000));

                Console.WriteLine("The seventh digit is {0}", numbers6 =(sin % 10000 / 1000));

                Console.WriteLine("The eighth digit is {0}", numbers7 = (sin % 1000 / 100));

                Console.WriteLine("The ninth digit is {0}", numbers8 =(sin % 100 / 10));

                Console.WriteLine("The tenth digit is {0}", numbers9 = (sin % 10));

                // Beginning of validation 
                //obtaining product of the sin using provided multipliers

                product = ((numbers1 * 1) + (numbers2 * 2) + (numbers3 * 1) + (numbers4 * 2) + (numbers5 * 1) + (numbers6 * 2) + (numbers7 * 1) + (numbers8 * 2));
                Console.WriteLine("The product {0}", product);

                // using div and mod to get numbers for the sum of digits

                sum = (((numbers1 * 1)+ (numbers2 * 2) % 10) +((numbers2 * 2) / 10) + (numbers3 * 1) + ((numbers4 * 2)%10) + ((numbers4 * 2)/10) + (numbers5 * 1) + ((numbers6 * 2)%10)+((numbers6 * 2)/10) + (numbers7 * 1) + ((numbers8 * 2)%10) + ((numbers8 * 2)/10));


                //Console.WriteLine("sum = {0}", sum);
                //Test to see if sum % 10 subtracted by 10 will give final digit

                test = (10 -(sum % 10));
               // Console.WriteLine("{0}", test);
                test = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());



                Console.ReadLine();
                //Display the results
                //Console.WriteLine("first = {0}, second = {1}, third = {2}, fourth = {3}, fifth = {4}, sixth = {5}, seventh = {6}, eighth = {7}, ninth = {8}",
                             //numbers1, numbers2, numbers3, numbers4, numbers5, numbers6, numbers7, numbers8, numbers9);

                valid = false;
                if (test > numbers9)
                {
                    if (test == numbers9)
                        valid = true;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("{0}", valid);

                valid = false;
                if (numbers9 > test && test < numbers9)
                {
                    valid = true;
                }



                Console.WriteLine("{0}", valid);

                Console.ReadLine(); 
        }



            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: your sample is very long - check out http://www.sscce.org for future questions.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need all those Console.ReadLine()? If you debug your code, you'll see that its stoping there to read something (twice!) from the console before printing the result.

```
...
test = (10 -(sum % 10));
// Console.WriteLine("{0}", test);
test = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.ReadLine();
...
```

You should read the SIN, validate it, print the result.

If you want to validate a second SIN if the first fails, you can do something like this:

```
int numberOfValidations = 0;
bool validSIN = false;

do{
// read SIN
// validate
// print result

numberOfValidations++;

}while( !validSIN || numberOfValidations <= 2);
```

**EDIT**

Here's a working demo on Ideone with your code:

<kbd>[DEMO](http://ideone.com/G5zfhA)</kbd>

Comment: okay i removed the excess readlines but i still have the issue where it wont validate the sin

Comment: @Shahze123 i've tested your code without the unnecessary readlines and it validates the SIN printing the output. Try to do some debuging to find out what's happening on your if's conditions.

Comment: @Shahze123 I've edited my response to include a Demo with your code (plus the do-while to check a second SIN if the first fails). It validates two SINs and outputs the validation results.

Comment: Thanks it's almost what i was looking for but not quite since it displays true and false for one of the sins, but its a great reference for anyone else who might be validating with multiple conditions, thanks to your help i was able to make my code work and figured out that if i just placed all the true conditions in one line instead of multiple it works out just fine

Comment: @Shahze123 yes, I left those two ifs/writelines because they could be helpful to you. To improve the readability of your code, you should have a method `bool IsValidSIN( int sin )` that applies the validation and returns a `boolean` with the validation result. You would end up with `if( IsValidSin( sin ) ){ Console.WriteLine("Valid!"); } else { Console.WriteLine("Not Valid!"); }`